# Combine several imageData structures into one canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs

I'm using `Konvajs` framework to work with `canvas`. I need to create three shapes (slots) and make some manipulations. It works but also I need to work with pixels, I get image via `getImageData`, store it in internal structure then use for manipulation.

```
var c = this.layer.getCanvas();
var ctx = c.getContext();
this.slots[name].data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.stage.getWidth(), this.stage.getHeight());
```

when the job is done, I want to combine those `imageData` structures into one but I can't. Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194267/putimagedata-how-to-keep-old-pixels-if-new-pixels-are-transparent) I try to do it, but always get:

> konva.min.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

This is my snippet of code:

```
var c = layer.getCanvas();
var ctx = c.getContext(); 

for (var slot_name in this.slots) {
  console.log('Slot', slot_name);
  var slot_data = this.slots[slot_name].data;
  var c2 = layer.getCanvas();
  var ctx2 = c2.getContext();
  ctx2.putImageData(slot_data, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(c2, 0, 0);
}
var imageData3 = c.toDataURL({pixelRatio: 1});
zip.file('scene.png', imageData3.substr(imageData3.indexOf(',') + 1), {base64: true});
```

Where is my mistake?

**UPDATE:**

changed line:

```
ctx.drawImage(c2, 0, 0);
```

to:

```
ctx.drawImage(c2._canvas, 0, 0);
```

and canvas saves but I see only the last saved picture. Why?

Answer (score 0):

`var c2 = layer.getCanvas();` - canvas here is not native canvas, it is Konva wrapper. So you have an error why you are trying to draw it.

To get reference to native canvas you can use: `var c2 = layer.getCanvas()._canvas;`.